# How to efficiently get info from all Docker containers running on a server via SSH?

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, ssh, paramiko

I need to get info of all the docker containers running on a remote server via SSH. There may be several hundred of docker containers running simultaneously. What's the most efficient way to get all the info? 
Rest API is not an option. 
What I need to do is

```
ssh root@blah.com 
execute docker container ls 
# get containers info 
for container_id in containers:
    execute docker inspect container_id
```

I cannot write the output of commands to files.

1. multiple SSH connections? How can I do this with paramiko?
2. running multiple commands simultaneously through one SSH connection? Can this be done through paramiko?

Answer (score 0):

You could run a Python script using [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

It would be faster because only one process to inspect all containers is better than to run **docker** for each one.

PD: And, of course, it can be done with **paramiko**.

Comment: thanks. but doesn't docker-py call the rest API behind the scene?

Comment: Yes.  But that Python script would be running on the server.

Comment: hmm, I'm not allowed to install anything on the target server.

Answer (score 0):

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(Ip, Port, UserName, PassWord)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("docker ps | sed -n '2,$p' |awk '{print $1}'")
#docker container id list
conIdList = stdout.readlines()
```

After get container id list, you can use multi threads/Asynchronous to exec ssh command `docker inspect ContainerID`, I think paramiko can deal it, but may be a time-consuming.